# Changing logo on specific language

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, polylang

I have this multilingual website. Is there a way I can change the logo to a different logo after I switch to "Arabian?"

I am using Polylang plugin at the moment and this is what I have scrummed together:

```
if (pll_default_language() == 'lang1') { ?>
    <img src="http://umar-project.mlab.napravi.online/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/logo-white-eng.png" alt="">
    <?php } else { ?>
     <img src="http://umar-project.mlab.napravi.online/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/logo-whiteara.png" alt="">
    <?php } ?>
```

I'm using WordPress. Can anyone help me?

Comment: On this code just upload Arabian logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `pll_default_language` use [pll_current_language](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/).

`pll_default_language` will return always the same value, even when you change your website language.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it with that.

Answer (score 0):

i use `get_bloginfo('language')` for check polylang as

```
<?php
$currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
if($currentlang=="en-GB") { ?>

<?php } elseif($currentlang=="pl-PL") { ?>

<?php } ?>
```